# {fmt} Using compile-time format strings with SQL

Tags: c++, fmt

What I'm looking to do is make a SQL query builder using fmtlib with the ideal syntax being:

```cpp
void run_query(fmt::string_view format, fmt::format_args args) {
  ...
}

template <typename S, typename... Args>
void query(const S& format, Args&&... args) {
  run_query(format, fmt::make_args_checked<Args...>(format, args...));
}

std::string query = query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '{}'", 123);
```

Obviously this would allow SQL injection so I would like to pass each argument to an SQL escape function. I found a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600105/c-fmt-library-formatting-a-single-argument-with-just-format-specifier) which looked like I could make work but the library has changed and that example no longer works. I also looked at some old docs and there was something called [ArgVisitor](https://fmt.dev/4.1.0/api.html#_CPPv4I00EN3fmt10ArgVisitorE) which I also thought might work but that has been removed too.

I understand that the idea of format strings in SQL query building is controversial but I would like to preserve type safety, ease of use, and compile time format string checking.

Comment: FWIW, the gist of SQL parameter sanitization is doubling each single quote found.

Comment: Why not just use prepared statements and not have to worry about escaping?

Comment: I don't agree that this is the *ideal* syntax. And prepared statements are safer and much faster (at least on SQLite3) than formatted statements.  With my SQLite3 wrapper, which is quite complex and based on our internal framework, your example would look like that: `database->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?", 123, &results);`. Where `results` is an array of dictionaries. Everything on a single statement.

Comment: What SQL library are you using? Does it have prepared statements like sqlite3?

Answer (score 1):

In [{fmt} 8.x](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/releases/tag/8.0.0) you should pass a format string as `fmt::format_string` which enables compile-time checks on compilers that support C++20 `consteval`:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

void run_query(fmt::string_view format, fmt::format_args args) {
  // ...
}

template <typename... T>
void query(fmt::format_string<T...> fmt, T&&... args) {
  run_query(fmt, fmt::make_format_args(args...));
}

int main() {
  query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '{}'", 123);
}
```